# Windows Back Up

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I have an external hard drive that I've used to create a manual back up by periodically copying data to it.

Is it possible to set up the windows 7 back up tool to continue using this back up? Could I create a backup which backs up the current version my pictures to the version of my pictures on the external hard drive for example? Sort of like a contribute type of back up?

Comment: Are you asking so that all new files are copied and overwrite where 2 files have the same name, or to keep all versions?

Comment: Any reason why you want to stick with Windows 7 backup as opposed to using a 3rd party program for that? There are some very simple and robust backups that fit your bill exactly.

Comment: Where "newer" files are copied and overwrite exisiting files. I have previously used Windows Sync Toy so have a backup of data. I would now like Windows Back up to use this data and overwrite as necessary. I don't know whether Windows Back Up only starts from a new blank back up?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard windows backup then [MSFT already has How To](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-change-automatic-backup-settings#1TC=windows-7) for automating backup.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm looking for a little more detail about the process as I don't want to start a "fresh" back up. Rather continue my exisiting one.